# Jnaeator equivalent for C# to wrap a C++ library

Tags: c#

I have a compiled C++ library (not COM or Assembly), its header and lib file With that library I have to write an utility in C# and Java language.

For Java I used JNAeator to wrap the external functions to Java class.
Is there anything similar for C#?

Comment: I don't know if you've come across pInvoke but just in case take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport-interop hope it helps

Comment: I'm curious about this too.

Comment: I tried PInvoke, but maybe I did not understand how to use it, I found only standard libraries and not custom one from a header file. Please consider that these functions have custom struts, I have to reproduce them.